# HtmlUnitDriver: enable/disable Basic Authentication?

Tags: java, selenium, basic-authentication, htmlunit-driver

The answers to [this question](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1729/) show how to enable Basic Auth with `HtmlUnitDriver`. However, how can I disable it again?

Note: the accepted answer to this question is correct, however, [due to a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1729/) it does not currently work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variant of [.addCredentials()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/DefaultCredentialsProvider.html#addCredentials(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)):

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();

        creds.addCredentials(username, password, hostname, port, realm);

        client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);
        return client;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's the correct way. However, by using Wireshark I can see that it still sends credentials to other domains also. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: I also created this, by the way: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1259

Comment: I update the answer, when your specify the hostname, it doesn't send the credentials.

Comment: I'm not by my computer now, but if you in your example do one getPage for Google.com with the abcd/efg credentials, then all subsequent getPage calls will also send credentials. I believe I tested with HtmlUnitDriver 2.18 as well as 2.19.

Comment: I thought your question is to do selective sending of the credentials to some specific host (was previous to your last question edit). Now, I guess you need to 'disable' the credentials. Right? DefaultCredentialsProvider was just [changed](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/11550/#diff-2) to have .removeCredentials()

Comment: That is precicely the problem: even if I specify a host, the credentials will still be sent to all hosts if that host has been contacted once. I will update my question to include all details. See http://pastebin.com/viqcg8Vg

Comment: I will make a complete, working example with Wireshark output.

Comment: Actually, the way you do it by using WebClient directly instead of HtmlUnitDriver seems to be working!